# In a Chromosome, 2 nm is the length of what?

Tags: dna, dna-sequencing, chromosome

this figure comes from [the nature](https://www.nature.com/scitable/nated/article?action=showContentInPopup&contentPK=310)

[image]

2 nm at the top right hand corner is the length of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNA is a long, thread-like molecule. [2nm is the **approximate** width of the DNA molecule.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Principles_of_Biochemistry/Nucleic_acid_I:_DNA_and_its_nucleotides)